Vuforia Package Search Request failed
I'm currently developing an app for HoloLens 2 using Unity 2021.3.19f1 and Vuforia 9-8-13. And it just shows this error to me.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Vuforia.EditorClasses.PackageVersionLookupService:Update ()
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()

I've googled this error but there's no proper solution for this. Has anyone ever met this error before?

I would try to update to the latest version of Vuforia Engine and recent unity version, it is quite possible that Hololens 2 support is broken in older versions.

As @emay mentioned, I would also recommend you to update to the latest version of Vuforia Engine and Unity 2022.3 LTS. This page in the Vuforia documentation can help you with the migration of your existing projects to Vuforia 10: https://developer.vuforia.com/library/project-migration/how-migrate-unity-project
